# Very slow MySQL search query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, join

```
SELECT
    cast(t1.destination as unsigned) as prefix,
    t2.destination as destination,
    FORMAT(sum(t1.terminatecauseid = 1), 0) as calls,
    IFNULL(sec_to_time(avg(case when t1.terminatecauseid = 1 then t1.sessiontime end)), 0) as aloc,
    CONCAT(TRUNCATE(sum(t1.terminatecauseid = 1) * 100 / count(*), 1), '%') as asr,
    sum(case when t1.terminatecauseid = 1 then t1.sessiontime end) as duration
FROM
    cc_call AS t1
        inner join
    cc_prefix as t2 ON t1.destination = t2.prefix
        inner join
    cc_country as t4 ON t1.destination like CONCAT(t4.countryprefix, '%')
WHERE
    t1.card_id = '133' AND t1.starttime >= ('2014-06-1')
group by t4.countryprefix
having duration is not null
order by duration DESC
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

Im making a search engine, I've come up with the correct queries to get the information I need. The DB is huge (1gb) and query sometime crashes httpd server.

This query is run, another similar query is run for pagination (to determine amount of pages), and a third query is run for total amount of duration and calls.

All that combined results in very bad performance.
Here's a sample of the db in a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4e2f3/21)

Any advice on how to improve performance is welcome.

I've tried using 'View' at some point with a different query to narrow down results, no luck with that yet.

Comment: What indexes do you have? Is the join on primary or declared secondary keys?

Comment: I've provided with a sqlfiddle for convenience, I made the joins with no consideration of indexes

Comment: A JOIN on a non-indexed field requires a full table scan. No wonder your query is slow.

Comment: you're using like with a '%', so this will be slow no matter what as it needs to go over all the destinations from t1 and match it against your wildcard string.... I'm sorry but this will not be fast unless you reorganise the data to have the prefix split from the rest as to avoid mysql free-text searching

Comment: As an aside, won't the date in `t1.starttime >= ('2014-06-1')` match anything greater than 2014-06-10 without the leading zero?

Comment: @Philipp Ok, can you provide an example maybe?

Comment: @user301. Thanks but Im bound to this data structure.

Comment: @Grim... it actually doesn't, and this is legacy code that's why it stays the same;)

Comment: @NitsanBaleli An example how to create an index on a MySQL database? Please read [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html) and then ask a separate question about anything you don't understand.

Comment: Can you index on a temp table? if so: Pre-process to create a temp table with an index; populating it with `... where  t1.destination like CONCAT(t4.countryprefix, '%')`; update statistics; replace the `inner join t4` with this temp table.

Comment: @radarbob you mean a 'View' ?

Comment: btw, what version of mysql are you running? and what storage engine

Comment: @user3012759 5.1.67, MyISAM

Comment: I mean temp table. Your SQL engine may drive whether one uses a permanent table, temp table, or view. In Sybase, I had to create a permanent table to make the indexing work. A view would not do in my case. And this technique did make a significant difference for my particular problem.

Comment: actually if you know that your prefix is fixed length you could stay with this query just make sure you add appropriate B-tree index (say first 2 3? chars) on the columns concerned, should speed up stuff quite a bit from non-indexed version.

Comment: @user3012759 actually prefixes are not fixed. ranges from 1-5 chars

Comment: but no more than 5, so index on destination(5*the size) should be fine for that, worth to give it a try imho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the structure of DB cannot be changed, and having that a wildcard search takes a really long time, I decided to use [mysql View](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html).

In the view I query all calls grouped by extensions, afterwards I've created another View with a wildcard search (alot faster than going through all of the DB all over again).

This also helped with total calls query, and pagination. response time is really good.